# Como posso salvar checkbox no banco com php?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, checkbox

Tenho vários componentes checkbox no site, cada uma com o valor do nome de um filme, como posso salvar no banco?

HTML de uma delas:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="filme">
```

Tem que ter o value ou o name diferente um do outro? Tipo checkbox do filme A Origem e outra do filme Insurgente?

é para o usuário salvar e ver posteriormente os filmes que já assistiu, então tem que ficar marcado

Comment: Qual é a finalidade do usuário marcar determinado filme? Locar?

Comment: é tipo salvar os filmes que ele já viu, esqueci de colocar isso kkkk

Comment: porque não faz um foreach() pra adicionar os campos no banco de dados? ai depois só faz um isset() pra verificar se existe no banco de dados, se tiver, marca como checado...

Comment: nem sei o que é isso kkk pode me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa colocar algo como `filme[]` no name dos checkboxes, e depois fazer um `foreach`, como foi dito pelo @AndréBaill.

Algo assim:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filme[]" value=filme_1>
<input type="checkbox" name="filme[]" value=filme_2>
<input type="checkbox" name="filme[]" value=filme_3>
<input type="checkbox" name="filme[]" value=filme_4>
```

E depois no seu código php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['filme'])){
    $listaCheckbox = $_POST['filme'];

    foreach ($listaCheckbox as $filme) {
        echo $filme;
        //aqui você salva no seu banco
    }
}

?>
```

Lembrando que antes de usar um valor vindo de um POST, você deve primeiro validá-lo por questões de segurança, principalmente se for salvar estes dados no banco de dados. Dê uma olhada no método [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php).